# Is there a way to resize this notification?

Tags: linux, notifications, shared-libraries, customization

I tend to listen to a lot of music on my laptop, which causes 'Now Playing' notifications to be displayed regularly. However, I find they are way too big for my screen, often disturbing my workflow.

I think I am using `libnotify`, or at least I'm able to send custom notifications to my own desktop with that library from the command line; unfortunately, I can't find any option to control the size of music notifications (Spotify in this case). Is there a way to do this or shall I install a replacement package?

I am using AwesomeWM in Arch Linux.

[image]

Comment: Not a programming question, try on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: It actually is, as the solution -which I have already found- involves programming. It's not a theoric question about, for example, how i-nodes work in Unix. This is absolutely code related and the answer must be a code snippet. Thank you anyway for the comments, I'll bear them in mind next time! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this to `rc.lua` fixed the problem:

`naughty.config.defaults['icon_size'] = 100`

Check out [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/awesomeWM/awesome/issues/1862).